# How can I turn off responses to Calendar invites?

Tags: macos, calendar

When I accept or decline a meeting invite, Calendar automatically sends an email to the person that invited me to the meeting.

OS X 10.10.2 calendar app

How can I turn this off so that no response is sent?

Comment: I have the same issue using Mail with an MS Exchange server. What server are you using? There is a "gesture" in Outlook for this (Accept => Do Not Send a Response) but not in Mail. I don't see any settings in Mail nor Calendar for this. Did you figure this out?

Comment: This now has a partial answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264615/85275 - but only for Spam invites

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using Calendar.app, including both macOS (OS X) and iOS.

Your best bet is to submit feedback on Apple's website: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

If enough of us do it hopefully they'll add the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, the Calendar app allows you to decline meetings without sending an email -- however you can't use the inbox window to do it and it doesn't appear as an explicit button like `Accept` / `Maybe` / `Decline`, and I have not found a way to do it in iOS. Also, I'm not sure what version of macOS it was added in, but I'm able to do it using Monterey (12.6).

What you want to do is "delete" the meeting rather than "decline" it. To do this:

1. Click on the meeting in your calendar view so that the meeting is highlighted, then hit the `Delete` key on your keyboard. (Alternately, you can right click the meeting and then click the `Delete` menu item.)
2. If it's a recurring meeting, a pop-up will ask you if you want to respond to `Only this event` or `All`. Click whichever one you intended.
3. Finally, you get a pop-up that asks if you want to `Delete and Notify` or `Delete and Don't Notify`. Hit **`Delete and Don't Notify`**.

[image: pop-up with delete and don't notify option]